# After I merged the vertices, the cracks are gone but it somehow created some weird link up on the mesh

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones, geometry

[Video reference](https://cloudmails-my.sharepoint.com/:v:/g/personal/tp053611_mail_apu_edu_my/EXimPi0MUUtCsx89d1Q2jdEBGR9qtdWoFq7KmpBWaOi5-g?nav=eyJyZWZlcnJhbEluZm8iOnsicmVmZXJyYWxBcHAiOiJPbmVEcml2ZUZvckJ1c2luZXNzIiwicmVmZXJyYWxBcHBQbGF0Zm9ybSI6IldlYiIsInJlZmVycmFsTW9kZSI6InZpZXciLCJyZWZlcnJhbFZpZXciOiJNeUZpbGVzTGlua0NvcHkifX0&e=SWlLWv):

Initially, when I tried to rig the mesh, it created some cracks in certain areas, but after I merged the vertices, it seemed to create some weird link up like shown in the video, any suggested solution?

[image]

Comment: Not enough info without seeing your file ... But it seems like weight paint issue.

Comment: another possibility is that the topology is bad, with overlapping faces etc